# Change the width div after pressing li or if # in the URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I've written a code that sets the width for the .line when you press the selected li. I also want, if url contains #first to give .line the width of element#first. Why doesn't this code work. Please help me.

```
var set = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var line = document.querySelector('.line');

if(window.location.hash == "#first"){
  lineScale(document.querySelector('#first'));
};

for(i=0;i<set.length;i++)set[i].addEventListener('click',lineScale(el));
function lineScale(el){
  line.style.transform = 'scaleX(' + el.getBoundingClientRect().width + ')';
};
```

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#first" id="first">First</a></li>
  <li><a href="#second" id="second">Second</a></li>
  <li><a href="#third" id="third">Third</a></li>
  <li><a href="#fourth" id="fourth">Fourth</a></li>
  <span class="line"></span>
</ul>
```

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.line {
  display: block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 2px;
  transform-origin: left;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, instead of `.addEventListener('click',lineScale(el));` you should have `.addEventListener('click',lineScale);`

Comment: Then it will work, but not in two cases.

Comment: @Yousaf It was just a mistake I fixed the code.

Comment: The first argument to the event listener callback is not the element, but an *event*. Inside of the callback function, just use `this` to reference the element being acted upon: thus, `this.getBoundingClientRect().width` instead of `el.getBoundingClientRect().width`.

Comment: What about window.location.hash?

Comment: Test what about it? It looks like it should call your event handler if the hash is used. Now that you've changed the code there, is it still not calling the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues with your event listener for click.

One is that you are trying to include an argument in the adding of the event. This is preventing your event handler from being called (since the handler is `lineScale`, not `lineScale(el)`). Secondly, the first argument to the event handler is not the element but an event. You can use `this` in the event handler to reference the element that the event is occurring for.

Thus:

```
for(i = 0; i < set.length; i++)
  set[i].addEventListener('click', lineScale);

function lineScale(){
  line.style.transform = 'scaleX(' + this.getBoundingClientRect().width + ')';
};
```

When debugging your javascript, make use of the developer's console in your browser. It will show you errors that occur in the javascript. For example, when you have `.addEventListener('click', lineScale(el));` the developer's console in Chrome shows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: el is not defined
```

That's because, as it says, `el` is not defined in that context. After fixing that issue, when you tried to reference the `el` argument as an element, this error shows up in the developer's console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: el.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at HTMLLIElement.lineScale
```

You probably have other issues preventing you from achieving your ultimate goal, but this should get you much further without solving all of the individual problems. Additional problems should be posted as a separate question if you are having trouble with them.